# Angular CLI Jasmine Unit test Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RequestOptions: (?)

Tags: angular, jasmine

First i got this error No provider for ConnectionBackend! so i import it to my spec Although i am not importing it in my service

then i got No provider for RequestOptions! i imported it to my spec also, Although i am not importing it in my service

then i got this error : Can't resolve all parameters for RequestOptions: (?).

any suggestions?

BookingDataService spec

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BookingDataService } from './booking-data.service';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

describe('BookingDataService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [BookingDataService, Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([BookingDataService], (service: BookingDataService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

appComponent spec

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FindTripComponent } from './find-trip/find-trip.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        FindTripComponent
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

});
```

BookingDataService ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class BookingDataService {

  //create instance of http
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  //get data from json file
  fetchData() {
    return this._http.get('/assets/mockdata/mock.json').map(
      response => response.json()
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: are you using any `barrel` for your imports?

Comment: sorry i am new to angular, what do you mean with barrel?

Comment: In your `appComponent spec` file you are not injecting providers, that is the issue

Comment: which providers must i inject in `appComponent spec`?

Comment: No providers you injected.

Comment: so i must add `providers: []` in `configureTestingModule`  do you mean that?

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: yes i am available but can i send  the id and pw here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `BookingDataService spec` file,

Modify the `TestBed.configuration`

- Remove the providerrs Http, RequestOptions
- import the HttpModule

Comment: This displays a new error for me "Error: No provider for Http!". Anyone knows about this?

Comment: @EzekielInalegwuAkoji can you share your code or raise a different post

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I think this solution works. There were other dependencies required by my test, hence the error.